# Microsoft LUIS - startPos and EndPos in utterance and entities

Tags: json, azure, botframework, tokenize, azure-language-understanding

I am currently figuring out how it could be possible training LUIS without using the web UI. Especially I am thinking about finding a way to describe the app in a file and import and retrain it in LUIS. I know there was an implementation of that in Python with some limitations and for API version one.

When providing an utterance, I would like to be able doing somethink like this, where (Stockname) is an entity in my utterance:

```
What's the price of (stockName)?
```

When I want to generate the JSON for importing the app into LUIS, this needs to look like this:

```
                "utterances": [
              {
                "text": "What's the price of (stockName)?",
                "intent": "stockPrice",
                "entities": [
                  {
                    "entity": "stock",
                    "startPos": 6,
                    "endPos": 6
                  }
                ]
              },
```

The problem is **startPos** and **endPos**. As far as I understand, this is the position of the entity "word" in the tokenised utterance. I think LUIS transforms the utterance into the **tokenized tex**t "What ' s the price of (stockName) ?" and the entity is on position 6 (zero-based).

That means to generate the utterance list in importable JSON, I need to be able to either get the tokenized utterance text from LUIS or tokenize it myself.

**Is there another way of achieving this?**

**Is there a way to get the tokenised text back from LUIS, so I can generate my app in JSON format?**

Best regards and thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I think that your understanding about the `startPos` and `endPos` values of the Entity is incorrect.

First of all, in the latest version of `LUIS` those parameters are named `startIndex` and `endIndex`. Not sure if you are using a v1 or if the `JSON` you posted is just a custom schema you are creating.

But in any case, the values expected there are:

**startIndex**: The index of the first character of the entity within the given text

**endIndex**: The index of the last character of the entity within the given text

So, for example in an utterance like "Who is Ezequiel Jadib?" where "Ezequiel Jadib" is an entity (let's say People), LUIS will return the following values for the `startIndex` and `endIndex` properties:

[image]

where 7 is the first character of the entity (the "E") and 20 is the last one (the "b"), taking into account that is zero based.

Knowing this, I think that is easier to generate the start/end values as you just need to know where your entity starts and where it ends.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. But I was referring to the apps - Import application REST interface: https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c31

It shows kind of the same example mentioned in my first post. I was thinking I could generate this JSON and import it.
But, as you mentioned, I could also make one API call for each intent, utterance or entity - its not that convenient but I guess it will work also...